# Unable to catch 'email-already-in-use' error

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

```
class FirebaseAuthFailure implements IauthFailure {
  final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn;

  FirebaseAuthFailure(this.firebaseAuth, this.googleSignIn);
  @override
  Future<Either<AuthFailure, Unit>> registerWithEmailAndPassword(
      {required EmailAddress emailAddress, required Password password}) async {
    final emailAddressStr = emailAddress.value
        .fold((left) => throw UnexpectedValueError(left), (right) => right);
    final passwordStr = password.value
        .fold((left) => throw UnexpectedValueError(left), (right) => right);
    try {
      await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailAddressStr, password: passwordStr);
      return right(unit);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        return left(const AuthFailure.emailalreadyinuse());
      } else {
        return left(const AuthFailure.servererror());
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the code which I have used.I am actually handling that [email-already-in-use] but when I register with an email and again register with that email a snackbar should be shown but nothing is showing.The code for snackbar is below:

```
 BlocConsumer<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                state.authfailureorsuccess.fold(
                    () {},
                    (either) => either.fold((failure) {
                          FlushbarHelper.createError(
                            message: failure.map(
                                cancelledbyuser: (_) => 'Cancelled',
                                servererror: (_) => 'Server Error',
                                emailalreadyinuse: (_) =>
                                    'Email Already In Use',
                                invalidemailandpasswordcomnination: (_) =>
                                    'Invalid Email And Password Combination'),
                          ).show(context);
                        }, (_) {}));
              },
```

The error I am getting in the console is below

> I/FirebaseAuth(29404): Creating user with nidhinvninan29@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
> W/System  (29404): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
> E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(29404): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signUpPassword)with exception - The email address is already in use by another account.
> E/flutter (29404): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error [firebase_auth/email-already-in-use] The email address is already in use by another account. occurred in Instance of 'AuthBloc'.

I have tried giving

```
e.code == 'email-already-in-use:'
```

```
e.code == 'firebase_auth/email-already-in-use'
```

But nothing is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch a `FirebaseAuthException`, and not `PlatformException`. Try this:

```
try {
  await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(...);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  // check here for e.code == 'email-already-in-use'
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I'd also remind everyone to read the documentation, in this case: [Error Handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/errors).